# How can I open Internet Explorer 9 in IE7 mode by default?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, internet-explorer-7, webdriver

I want to set my IE to always open in IE7 mode.

I mostly develop in Chrome, and for purposes of efficiency and 80/20 principle, I assume that IE9 looks and behaves mostly like Chrome.

And I assume that if something looks and works decent enough in IE7, most of the time IE8 will be fine.

So I just want my Internet Explorer to always open as version 7 without me having to change it in the developer panel.

This will also be useful for my Selenium WebDriver functional tests that I want to run in IE7.

Thoughts?

Comment: IE9 is nothing like Chrome. IE9 still falls quite short of CSS3 support. Also IE7 mode of IE9 is NOT the IE7 engine, so you'll find that some bugs only present themselves in an actual IE7 environment but not in an emulated IE7 mode of IE9.

Comment: For my purposes, IE9 and Chrome behave similarly enough, even though I know they use different rules and behave slightly differently in corner cases and won't be identical pixel-to-pixel.  The minor differences don't merit the large amount of additional testing effort it would take.  I also know that IE7 mode of IE9 isn't the same as real IE7, but until we can find a convenient way to use virtual machines, it is the best (only) option.

Comment: You can force IE9 to use IE7 doctype rendering. That's about it. This is not the same as true IE7 mode (which again, is not the same as true IE7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/internet-explorer-google-chrome-tab/ and it seems to open in IE7 mode by default.

There is still the caveat (of course) that this fake IE7 isn't the same as a native install of IE7.  But this might be a decent trade-off.

Comment: I was unable to use this approach. I've successfully forced Chrome instance launched by Selenium to use this plugin and to load my page using the IE tab, but that's about it - all tests fails as Selenium doesn't seem to be able to use the page loaded that way (tests timeout after doing nothing).

Answer (score 3):

could these meta tags work for you?

```
<!-- Force IE9 to IE8 compatibility mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<!-- Force IE9 to IE7 compatibility mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

Comment: Nope, I don't want to change how it opens in OTHER people's browsers, just mine.  And putting in conditional code that detects whether the user is me (and then if it's me, adding these meta tags) isn't ideal either.

Answer (score 1):

The commenters are right - you should not assume that Chrome will act the same as IE9, IE7, or anything. And furthermore, IE9 running in compatibility view (whether it is set from Developer Tools or from the Compatibility View settings) can not be counted on to act the same as IE7.

But, if what you want is for IE9 to always launch in Compatibility View, just set that in your browser's options (the bottom checkbox in your Compatibility View settings).

Comment: Thanks. See my other comments about browser differences.  If you are telling me to choose "Internet Explorer 9 Compatibility View" (the last option in the "Browser Mode" dropdown of the F12 Developer Tools), that's not the answer, as that does not force IE7.