# How to maintain session in selenium while opening new window

Tags: selenium

How to maintain session in selenium while opening new window. I am clicking a download button after which a file should be asked to download(IE). But running via selenium it opens a new window asking again to login???

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. I don't know your implementation, but maybe you're *cleaning cache* with each new browser Instance. Try to find why it's opening new Window instead of using same browser instance and just open it's download_window. How you handle default_window can also be the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Manually clicking on the download button just asks for the file to download.

Comment: Clicking it via code. Common.driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1)).click();                                                                  Just opens a new window asking to login again

Comment: Yes - as expected. What *Driver are u using? If it is GhostDriver, as far as I remember I had to use [AutoIt](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/) in order to handle file upload. But it also supports downloading.

Comment: m using InternetExplorerDriver with IEDriverServer.exe...Application is IE compatible only

Comment: If it is as expected. What is the solution?

Comment: Actually IE_Driver is the least I had to work with. But I'll try to help you anyway with this final suggestion for your problem - check your IE version and compability view - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466538/change-ie9-to-ie8-with-selenium-webdriver-in-ruby)  and also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416663/how-can-i-open-internet-explorer-9-in-ie7-mode-by-default).

Comment: Its same in every IE version. The problem persists because the session logs out after running it via code. It cud only be solved if the session is maintained.